# How to allow different types of tokens in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

In my spring based service, I have enabled Oauth2 Resource server based authentication using `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation and following fillter code.

```java
http.
....
.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver)).build();

// The authenticationManagerResolver is initialized with correct Auth0 IssuerURL and Audience
```

Now, I want to enable tokens that were generated using a trusted Public/Private key combination as well for my application.

How can I edit the above filter to allow Auth0 generated tokens and the tokens generated using the Private / Public keys interchangably..

Comment: I'm curious, why didn't the post below help or even answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of drilling of documentation, found that Springboot does have a native way to accomplish the requirement.

Using [Multi-tenancy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html) feature, different JWT decoders can be registered.

The Auth0 decoder will be initialized the `domain`.
The Public key based decoder can be initialized with the relevant public key.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use different security filter-chain beans for each request authorization mechanism: you can provide a `securityMatcher` to specify which requests a `securityFilterChain` processes and the criteria can be about anything you like, including the `Authorization` header format.

I used the following sample to bridge from `basic` authentication to OAuth2 client-credentials flow (accept queries from a legacy client maintained by another team with no bandwidth to migrate it to OAuth2):

```java
http.securityMatcher((HttpServletRequest request) -> {
    return Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)).map(h -> {
        return h.toLowerCase().startsWith("basic ");
    }).orElse(false);
});
http.httpBasic(withDefaults());
http.userDetailsService((String username) -> {
    return new User(username, "", List.of());
});
http.authenticationManager(new OidcClientCredentialsFlowAuthenticationManager(authServerBaseUri, tokenEndpointsProperties, authenticationManagerResolver));
http.sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
...
```

Defining a first standard OAuth2 resource server security filter-chain for requests with a `Bearer` authorization header and another security filter chain for requests secured with a public key should be just as easy as done above.

Comment: The post doesn't solve the problem for me. Given both of my cases are expecting a JWT token. So, it wouldn't be possible to have securityMatcher unless token is decoded for issuer.

Comment: I had misunderstood your question: thought you were using keys to authorize requests, not in another issuer to sign JWTs